# Is it better to create a function that is only called in one place, or use an arrow function?

Tags: javascript

For example, if I have an arrow which I want to call `filter()` on, is it better to do something like this:

```
tasks.filter((task) => {
    if (task.completed && hideCompletedTasks) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
)
```

or extract the function logic out and call the function one time.

```
tasks.filter((task) => filterCompletedTasks(task));

function filterCompletedTasks(task){
    if (task.completed && hideCompletedTasks) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: "better" is rather subjective and criterion-dependent; what do you think constitutes "better"? Also note that your second example could be written as simply `tasks.filter(filterCompletedTasks)`, no arrow required.

Comment: It totally depends on the use case. If you think "filterCompletedTasks" function will be used somewhere else then the second approach is more abstract and reusable as it is a pure function and it will always give you completed tasks when provided with tasks.

Comment: I guess I mean readability and maintainability in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It is not efficient or more readable to use if on booleans to return true or false:

Why not

```
const filterCompletedTasks = task.filter(task => task.completed && hideCompletedTasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the first logic i.e.

```js
tasks.filter((task) => {
    if (task.completed && hideCompletedTasks) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs, if you're only going to use that function only for that special ocassion, there's no need to take out the function (unless its too big and you want to isolate it), but if you're gonna reuse that function in other filters, then it'd be a good idea creating a separate function for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach,

```
tasks.filter((task) => {
    if (task.completed && hideCompletedTasks) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
);
```

Same logic can be written as,

```
tasks.filter(task => task.completed && hideCompletedTasks);
```